# MFC Link Control looks/acts as a common button when runtime

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have to maintain a very old MFC application (Dialog based), and now I need to add a hyperlink to the UI.

I use Visual Studio 2022 to do the work and found there is a "MFC Link Control" in toolbox.
After dragging it to the UI and trying it in dialog test (Ctrl + T), it worked fine. It is shown with blue color and underline font, and when I clicked it, it can go to the URL I set.

But when I run it, everything changed. It looks like a common button, with no blue color or underline. And when I clicked it, nothing happend.

I created a new MFC solution to test the MFC Link Control, it worked as expected. So I guess something in the old solution prevents the MFC Link Control to work, but I don't know what is it.
I have wasted 4 hours on it already, so if someone can give me some information, it will be very helpful.

- There is already no information about which IDE is used when the old application is developed origally. Now it is built by Visual Studio 2010 when release.

Update: The project supports multi-language. The .rc file is mixed by English, Chinese and Janpanese and the file encoding is Shift-Jis (Not unicode or UTF-8). Maybe it has some influence.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. You mention that the original project (the one that doesn't work) was built with VS 2010 - maybe that's the issue. Try updating it to use the VS2022 toolset.

Comment: @Adrian Mole Thanks for your reply. I think the original project is not created by VS 2010. it is more older. The only thing known is the project is maintained by VS 2010 now. 
And yes, I already upgraded it to VS 2022 toolset.

Comment: I would check the project's manifest, SysLink controls require comctl32.dll version 6, per the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/syslink-overview).

Comment: @Constantine Georgiou Thanks for your reply, It's very inspiring. I read the documentation and tried it, but unfortunately it not works. I used ProcessExplorer to confirmed the EXE was using comctl32.dll with version 6.10, but nothing changed.

Comment: Since you are using VS2022, and if you can create a test project that does this on demand, why not use the Report a project too in VS2022 on help menu?

Comment: @Andrew Truckle Uh...I don't understand what you said completely. Do you mean use the "feedback" to send the problem to Microsoft? I will try it.

Comment: Yes, that’s right.  

Comment: @Holsety please [edit] and show a picture of the dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searched the Microsoft documentation a little and found the following:

- The application must be using ComCtl32.dll version 6 (or 6.10), see [About SysLink Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/syslink-overview).
- Check the project's manifest in Visual Studio. Also, in the project's *General Properties* check the *Windows SDK Version* and *Platform Toolset* options. An older project may be using an older version of ComCtl32.dll. Also check [Enabling Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview).
- The application must call `InitCommonControlsEx()` with the `ICC_LINK_CLASS` flag included in the controls' bitmask, see [How to Create SysLink Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-syslink-controls). In MFC this is done in the `InitInstance()` function of your `CWinApp` class. `ICC_LINK_CLASS` is **not** included in the `ICC_WIN95_CLASSES` bitmask (check the definitions in *CommCtrl.h* header file), so you may have to add it youself, eg `ICC_WIN95_CLASSES | ICC_LINK_CLASS`.

**EDIT:**
Add the following line somewhere in your source (eg in the app class souce):

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

This tells the linker to load comctl32 version 6.

Comment: I tried your suggestions.

Comment: **It still not works.** **1.** Using ProcessExplorer to confirmed the EXE was using comctl32.dll with version 6.10. And I also confirmed when startup, it loaded this one: "C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.19041.1110_none_a8625c1886757984\comctl32.dll", which is same to a little sample can show the MFC Link Control.
**2.** I created a manifest like the document. I confirmed windows sdk version is 10.0, and platform toolset is v143.
**3.** I called InitCommonControlsEx() in InitInstance() with "ICC_WIN95_CLASSES | ICC_LINK_CLASS".

Comment: Now I use a label contol with style setting like a hyperlink as a backup plan, if I can't solve this problem finally.

Comment: @Holsety, try creating the link control programmatically, not through the resource script. The window class name is `WC_LINK`. Not that this will be the final solution, but it can show whether the control is available in the control library and it is properly initialized. If it can be created this way then there must be some issue with the project settings or the script.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I'm modifying other functions, so I will try it later. Anyway, I will let you know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I knew why.
Because MFC is very old so I considered a lot of possibilities, but the truth is simple.

There are other dialogs in the project, and when I added MFC Link Control to them, they are all OK. So the problem must not be in the project settings, like dll version.

I made another new dialog and copy source code to it little by little, and when I copied the function "OnInitDialog()", it happened.

I JUST missed calling to the base class's "OnInitDialog()". I added the calling then it worked.

If the miss caused a runtime error I think I can notice it, but it just disply a link control as a button...

@Constantine Georgiou you helped me a lot, and I also got some useful information. So I accepted your answer.